# WPF bind command to list view with command parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question I have a simple list view in XAML that binds to collection of item:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MainModel.Input}" Background="Black"  SelectionMode="Single" x:Name ="InputList">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InputList, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <!-- here is column binding but irrelevant to this question -->
</ListView>
```

And command looks like:

```
    public ICommand CheckItemCommand => new Command(parm =>
    {
        responseDetails = new ResponseDetailsWindow { DataContext = new ResponseDetails((Input)parm, this) };
        responseDetails.ShowDialog();
    });
```

I could just bind it to SelectedItem but it is a special case, meaning that this collection is very dynamic and if I select item during list change I will execute command that many times as selected item changed position in observable list.

With command I will just send one state and I do not care what happens on observable.

It should work that id select some item on list commands fires with parameter, and well only first part works command is starting but as a parameter I am getting null, I also tried using just binding but then I am getting view model not selected value from list. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` to a source property and simply execute the command from this source property? The item hasn't been selected by the time the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` to a source property and simply execute the command from the setter of this source property.

The item hasn't been selected by the time the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` fires.